# How to distinguish email-authenticated account or not on FirebaseAuthnication

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm using Firebase and I'm very new about this.
I'm using Authentication function in Firebase and coding about error handling.
And I guess there are two patterns about `email-already-in-use` like:

1. Email was registered and email Authentication completed as well, and users gonna send same email address and firebase announces the error above.
2. Email was registered but Authentication was not completed yet, and users gonna send same email address and firebase announces the error above.

I want distinguish these status but `FirebaseAuthException` always throw `email-already-in-use` in common, how can I handle this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "email Authentication completed"? And how do you sign-up (i.e. "register") users? Which method are you calling for that?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm using the method below 
1. auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword() // user email & pass registered in Firebase
2.user.sendEmailVerification()// Firebase sends email to users to identify
3.User open the email and finally entire authentication process completed

Comment: In this context `email Authentication completed` means #3 above, not only registered in Firebase but also user opened a email from Firebase and the account became effective status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your comments under your question:

> I'm using the method below 1. `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` //
> user email & pass registered in Firebase
> 2. `user.sendEmailVerification()`// Firebase sends email to users to identify 3.User open the email and finally entire authentication
> process completed

> In this context email Authentication completed means #3 above, not only
> registered in Firebase but also user opened a email from Firebase and
> the account became effective status.

From your comments it is not 100% clear what you mean by "the account became effective status".

When you call the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method from the front-end, upon success, the user is created in the Firebase Authentication service (i.e. is signed-up) **and** is automatically signed-in.

The fact that the user's email is verified (with `user.sendEmailVerification()`) **or not** will not impact the behaviour of the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` if you try to create a user with an email that is already existing in the Firebase Authentication service. In other words, whether the email is verified or not, the `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` method will prevent you creating another user with the same email and will return an `email-already-in-use` error.

---

If you want, for a given email, to be able to create a new user with the same email if the user previously created with this email hasn't verified his/her email, you'll have to build your own verification system and create the Firebase Authentication user (i.e. account) yourself, e.g. with the [Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users) in the back-end.

---

#### Update following your comments below:

> Is this kind of process, creating user account and verifying the
> user's email, common in Firebase authentication ?

Yes, verifying the email before allowing a user to interact with the Firebase back-ends (DBs or Cloud Storage) is common.

Not only you can verify in your front-end if the email is verified (with the [`emailVerified`](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/emailVerified.html) property), but, **more important**, you can check this property in security rules (i.e. in the back-end).

More details [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.Request?hl=en%5D#auth) in the doc and see below an example of a security rule function that checks if the user's email is verified:

```
function isUserEmailVerified() {
    return request.auth.uid != null && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but If we use `Sign-in-methond` function in Firebase authentication,  only email verified users are teated as effective account right ?
So in case like, who's account was created by createUserWithEmailAndPassword() but forgot to open email, finally I want let see email box or send-email again

Comment: What do you exactly mean by "Sign-in-methond function in Firebase authentication"? Can you point to the exact method in the documentation?

Comment: Hi, here is (doc) [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/email-link-auth?hl=en]

Comment: I'm sorry but `Email Links` must be official named function in Firebase

Comment: Thanks for the link, but then you are not using the `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()` as you mentioned in the comment under your question. This is a different case.

Comment: I'm sorry finally maybe I'm confusing. Email Links must be very different function and firstly I should ask in this way as followings:

Comment: 1. I'm using `auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword()' method to create user account

Comment: 2. However, afraid that user may make some mistakes to input their email address

Comment: 3. So, I use `user.sendEmailVerification()` as well to identify the user.

Comment: 4. Finally, I found `auth.currentUser.emailVerified;` method to identify whether the users are verified by email or not

Comment: Is this kind of process, creating user account and verifying the user, not general or common in Firebase authentication ?

Comment: I was going to point you to the exact same property, [emailVerified](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/emailVerified.html). So check this property in order to allow or not a user to interact with the Firebase back-ends (DB or cloud Storage). **IMPORTANT: You can check this property in security rules** in addition to checking it in the front-end

Comment: See the update in my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot and it was really helpful me. I'm gonna learn more about security rules in Firebase with official docs. Thanks again!